# i want to solve a linear equation using python : LinAlgError Singular matrix

Tags: python

[this my equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiepI.png)

```
import numpy as np
x=264
y=263
u=240
v=227
a = np.array([[1,x,y],[1,x,y],[0,0,0]])
b = np.array([u,v,0])
sol = np.linalg.solve(a,b)

print("sol=",sol)
```

Comment: You sure this equation is solvable?

Comment: Try with the least squares method if it isn't solvable

Comment: You have 6 unknowns and 2 equations. You will probably never find only one solution for this. For example one made up solution: `A=[u, 0, 0, v, 0, 0]`

Comment: True @pLOPeGG he does have a free variable

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a solver for this: there are infinitely many solutions (in most cases), one of them is:

```
a_1 = u
a_2 = 0
a_3 = 0
a_4 = v
a_5 = 0
a_6 = 0
```

I am pretty sure you misunderstood something.